# How secure is to use third party web service on a production website 

Tags: web-services, chat

For long I wanted an IM type discussion client on my production website instead of those *commenting things* ....i just came across this third party web-service at
http://aagmgyd6.yahoo.joyent.us/chat/index.html    ...I was just curious ...if i use it on my production system what cautions i must take ...is it secure ??? any other alternative ???

Regards
Shrey

Comment: Guys pls help on this ......any one from PHP or javascript domain ..any advice ??

Answer (score 1):

It's just some javascript that will run in the user's browser, so it won't affect your server at all. That's with just a cursory glance over the javascript.

The only risk you will have with something like this (and this is the same with anything third party that you use) is that if they go out of business and take the site hosting their code down, you're screwed.

How come you decided to go with an IM solution? Are you sure that people will hang around on your site waiting for other people to log on? Why not use something like [disqus](http://www.disqus.com)?